# domain redirecting to localhost/wordpress

Tags: wordpress, localhost

this is my first time, I am installing a wodrpress localhost(xampp) to main server.
According to tutorial I Imported database from local machine to main server. Changed the the table prefix and http://localhost/wordpress to https://example.com.

1. after installing theme domain shows empty theme.
   I changed all the http://localhost/wordpress used on theme. But didn't work.
   Then according to another tutorial I imported full localhost wordpress file. 
   Then It redirecting my domain to http://localhost/wp-wordpress. Then I decided to fully reinstall the wordpress and as per I removed file from public html which I uploaded. 
   Now my domain redirecting to http://localhost/wp-wordpress after removing files I uploaded.[Public html folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSMyS.png)
   [my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIMIL.png)
   After reinstalling wordpress on server admin dashboard working fine but domain redirecting to localhost/wp-wordpress

Comment: You need to update the home and site url in the `wp-options` table.

Comment: But sir I uninstalled my wordrpress fully though domain redirecting to localhost. So there's no wp_options.

Comment: Do one thing, Now, you uninstall the wordpress source code and database both. And after then you install the new wordpress source code with new create database. So, you can get the proper result. Thanks!

Comment: Does cgi-bin folder from contain any file? This folder is empty in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the url many ways in wordpress. You can use to change the url as you understand and follow the steps as I mentioned in below,

1. **Change WordPress URL in Admin Dashboard**
2. **Change WordPress URL in wp-config.php File**
3. **Change WordPress URL Directly in Database**
4. **Change WordPress URL With WP-CLI**

Get More understanding the details, Follow the article - [How to Change Your WordPress URL](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/change-wordpress-url/)

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

After checking wp-config.php and site_url,home_url in wp_options table in database. Take a view on .htaccess file too. This file should look like [this htaccess code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmfq6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please change the site_url from the **wp_option** table. There are 2 rows containing the website base url in the **wp_option** table. You need to change both url to the main domain url.
Thank you